# Query filesystem for list of files with certain attributes?

Tags: linq

I'd like to be able to query a folder (and subfolders) and get a list of files meeting certain criteria on specific attributes...so, for example, all files that have:

under c:\somefolder
file_extension = ".abc"
filesize between x and y KB
(filename like '%this' or filename like '%that%' and filename not like '%somethingelse%'
modifieddate between date1 and date2

Is this sort of thing possible using LINQ, and what would the syntax look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The syntax would look something like:

```
var files = from file in new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\some_folder")
                            .GetFiles("*.abc", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

            let lengthInKb = file.Length / 1024D
            let name = file.Name
            let modifiedDate = file.LastWriteTime.Date

            where  (lengthInKb >= x && lengthInKb <= y)
                && (name.EndsWith("this") || name.Contains("that")) 
                && !name.Contains("somethingelse")
                && (modifiedDate >= date1 && modifiedDate <= date2)

           select file;
```